# Batch set specific printer port

Tags: printing, batch-file, registry, port, default

I am trying to set a printers default port in batch. I need to use port FILE:
Here is what i have tried. Not sure if this is the right method to go about doing this.

> RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "Apple
>   LaserWriter 16/600 PS" PortName value:"FILE:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "Apple LaserWriter 16/600 PS" PortName "FILE:"
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt Williamson